# How to efficiently update items of a huge (100.000 items) array from a smaller (50 items) array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance, lookup

I have two arrays like this:

```
let a = [{id: 1, content: 10},{id: 2, content: 20},{id: 3, content: 30}]
let b = [{id: 1, content: 11},{id: 2, content: 21}]
```

where `a` is actually huge (~100k objects) and `b` is about 50 objects, where all the `id`s in the objects in `b` are found in `a`. I want to merge these arrays together such that if an object in `a` has a given id and an object in `b` has that same id, the object in `a` gets replaced by the object in `b`. So `{id: 1, content: 11}` from `b` would replace `{id: 1, content: 10}` from `a`. The output in this example would be

```
[{id: 1, content: 11},{id: 2, content: 21},{id: 3, content: 30}]
```

where the first two objects got replaced, but the third didn't because it wasn't in `b`.

**What I Tried:**

```
let func = (a,b) => {
    let aa = a.reduce((acc,cur) => ({
        ...acc,
        [cur.id]: cur
    }), {})
    let bb = b.reduce((acc,cur) => ({
        ...acc,
        [cur.id]: cur
    }), {})
    return Object.keys({...aa,...bb}).map(key => mergedObj[key])
}
```

So I convert each array (`a` and `b`) into an object (`aa` and `bb`), indexed by its `id`, then merge the two objects, then convert them back to an array.

**The Problem:**

The line `let aa = a.reduce ...` takes a very long time.

Is there a more efficient approach to this problem?

Comment: Are the `id`s in `a` successive :) (as in the example), or at least increasing? Do you repeat the operation for several `b`-data (in which case it makes sense to precompute the indices of `id`s)?

Comment: @kikon Unfortunately the `id`s are neither successive not increasing. And I don't repeat the operation on `b`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Merge 2 arrays of objects into a new one, based on object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689706/javascript-merge-2-arrays-of-objects-into-a-new-one-based-on-object-properties)

Comment: @gkeenley ... The performance killer is ... making excessive usage of rest parameter, spread syntax and destructuring assignement for each single iteration step. I suggest keeping it as simple as possible, thus a lookup based approach with references only since from the OP's example code there is no need for merging. It is more an updating replacement of existing item references.

Comment: @gkeenley ... I added [a realistic performance test which resemble the OP's production environment](https://jsbench.me/2flby3l6tp/1). An approach which due to a nested `findIndex` tasks (it's another iteration though it exists early) already implements exponential costs will fall back far behind any lookup based approach. In chrome, firefox, safari the latter is everywhere in between 80% to 84% percent slower than a lookup and reference based approach.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I was away and just reading the replies now. I will get to them today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my above comment ...

> *"... The performance killer is ... making excessive usage of rest parameter, spread syntax and destructuring assignement for each single iteration step. I suggest keeping it as simple as possible, thus a lookup based approach with references only since from the OP's example code there is no need for merging. It is more an updating replacement of existing item references."*

And because of that I would choose a lookup based approach where one would ...

1. create an object based lookup from the smaller source data-structure based on an item's `id` and
2. and finally map the larger target structure by looking up whether to update/replace the current item based on such an item's `id`.

Thus for creating the lookup one would fully iterate the smaller array exactly once, and for creating the updated structure one would fully iterate the larger array, also exactly once, with no other additional costs than the object based lookup which contributes close to nothing.

And everything would be based on references instead of shallow copies or structured clones.

In addition one would implement both tasks as function statements in order to take a little bit more advantage of the JIT compiler's runtime optimization.

Further code based optimization could be done but should depend on the performance of the hereby provided implementation of the just described approach.

```js
function aggregateIdBasedLookup(lookup, item) {
  lookup[item.id] = item;
  return lookup;
}
function updateItemFromBoundLookup(item) {
  return this[item.id] ?? item;
}

const largeTargetStructure = [
  { id: 1, content: 10 },
  { id: 2, content: 20 },
  { id: 3, content: 30 },
];
const smallerSourceStructure = [
  { id: 1, content: 11 },
  { id: 2, content: 21 },
];

const sourceLookup = smallerSourceStructure
  .reduce(aggregateIdBasedLookup, Object.create(null));

const largeUpdatedStructure = largeTargetStructure
  .map(updateItemFromBoundLookup, sourceLookup);

console.log({
  // largeTargetStructure,
  // smallerSourceStructure,
  // sourceLookup,
  largeUpdatedStructure,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

*"Having hade an intense discussion about how to design/setup a performance test which is close to the OP's production environment it turns out the misunderstanding about the above approach partially is due to how the lookup gets aggregated and how the result, the huge array of updated items, is created. It seems to be the `reduce` and `map` and function based style. The speaking names of the function statements couldn't help either"*

Because of that the next provides code example is a lookup and just `while` loop based implementation of the very same approach of the first provided code.

```js
const largeTargetStructure = [
  { id: 1, content: 10 },
  { id: 2, content: 20 },
  { id: 3, content: 30 },
];
const smallerSourceStructure = [
  { id: 1, content: 11 },
  { id: 2, content: 21 },
];
let item, idx;

// - aggregating the lookup object
//   which was done before via `reduce`.
idx = smallerSourceStructure.length;

const sourceLookup = Object.create(null);
while (item = smallerSourceStructure[--idx]) {
  sourceLookup[item.id] = item;
}

// - aggregating the huge result array
//   which was done before via `map`.
idx = largeTargetStructure.length;

const largeUpdatedStructure = Array(idx);
while (item = largeTargetStructure[--idx]) {
  largeUpdatedStructure[idx] = sourceLookup[item.id] ?? item;
}

console.log({
  // largeTargetStructure,
  // smallerSourceStructure,
  // sourceLookup,
  largeUpdatedStructure,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Additional Note**

The latest update of the before provided [performance test](https://jsbench.me/2flby3l6tp/1) unsurprisingly shows that the `while` loop replacement gives this lookup-variant a performance-boost.

That is why I said before along with the first provided example code ...

> *"Further code based optimization could be done but should depend on the performance of the hereby provided implementation of the just described approach."*

But since the advantage of the `while` loop implementation is not that critical in comparison to the `reduce`, `map` and function based implementation I for readability and code-reuse would always prefer the more expressive latter style.

Comment: Your solution clocks in at 0.0849609375 ms. (using console.time / console.timeEnd).

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... yes. But what does it mean? What does the test case look like? What is the performance gap in either direction in comparison to other implementations? Remember, the OP talks about ~100.000 objects which are going to be conditionally updated via an array of 50 objects.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... I added [a realistic performance test which resemble the OP's production environment](https://jsbench.me/2flby3l6tp/1). An approach which due to a nested `findIndex` tasks (it's another iteration though it exists early) already implements exponential costs will fall back far behind any lookup based approach. In chrome, firefox, safari the latter is everywhere in between 80% to 84% percent slower than a lookup and reference based approach.

Comment: I appreciate you doing that. However, your solution is 99.91% slower? https://jsbench.me/0mlbyglzra/1

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... The explanation is pretty simple. Your test case creates two arrays where with every iteration of the 50 items array the `findIndex` based search is always successful within the first 50 items of the 100.000 items array which of cause is not a realistic test scenario. Look into how my test case creates a 50 items array which is closer to what one can expect from a production environment. The lookup takes over when it comes to a full covering of a real 50 times 100.000 matrix and not just for the coverage of an effective 50 times 50 matrix as provided with your test case.

Comment: I updated the benchmark to make the smaller array match against the high end, 90,000 of 100,000. Mine is still faster. `for (let i = 90000; i < 50; i++) {` Can you create a benchmark showing what you mean? You need to put all your js in the test case, not part of it right?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... The test case is already there. I linked it several times. The most important part is the creation of a close to real world scenario; thus as for the OP's production environment the 50 items array needs to contain items with equally balanced `id` values from 1 to 100.000 (and not 50 items with `id` values always from just 1 to 50). Both the test data creation and all function statements are part of the test case **setup** and not of the benchmark test itself. The latter contains just the code which contributes to the immediate computing of the result.

Comment: the benchmark you posted has (2) of your functions in the "setup JavaScript" section. I'm eager to learn from others, however you are failing to make your case/point. Furthermore, you seem to be attempting to mislead. My code is shorter, simpler, and faster. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... 1/2 ... _"the benchmark you posted has (2) of your functions in the "setup JavaScript" section"_ ... correct, therefore they are exactly located where I said with my last comment they belong. The real benchmark test is .... **executing the `reduce` and `map` based computing of the final result** which is equal to the single `for` loop of yours. Btw ... there is no difference in whether the two functions are part of the setup area or of the test case code itself. Yet, the only reason for and still the only true explanation about the different result is ...

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... 2/2 ... how your test creates the 50 items array. I will repeat myself. Amongst the 50 items the `id` values need to equally cover the range of 0 to 99.999 or from 1 to 100.000. Your test case creates items with ascending `id`-values from 0 to 49 which leads to a test that always just needs to cover the search within a 50 time 50 matrix due to the big array's items which also  feature ascending id values from 0 to 49 for the first 50 items of this 10.000 items array which renders the following 99.950 items useless because the test case will never reach any of them.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... regarding following sentences of yours ... _"I'm eager to learn from others, however you are failing to make your case/point."_ ... I made my point, several times, always the same point, always clear and fair. ... _" you seem to be attempting to mislead"_ ... Please read all of my comments carefully again. Then go through both of our test cases, again carefully. ... _"Please prove me wrong."_ ... you already did it all by yourself.

Comment: I re-ran it putting the matches at the end of the big array and your is faster. I'm looking at the different approaches and having a hard time understanding your code - the `.reduce` function and how it is more efficient.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston ... It is neither the `reduce` nor the `map` function but the lookup based approach. Have a look into both, my updated answer with a 2nd, now `while` loop based, implementation of the same lookup based approach and my [updated performance test](https://jsbench.me/2flby3l6tp/1). It might help understanding that everything is about the lookup based approach and not how it is implemented.

Answer (score -2):

You're going to have to iterate over the smaller array no matter what method you use. `findIndex()` returns the index of that element and stops iterating through the larger array. So, it seems like the simplest approach is:

```js
let a = [{id: 1, content: 10},{id: 2, content: 20},{id: 3, content: 30}]
let b = [{id: 1, content: 11},{id: 2, content: 21}]

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  let thisID = b[i].id;
  let thisContent = b[i].content;
  a[a.findIndex(x => x.id === thisID)].content = thisContent;
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: my function is fastest, clocking in at 0.0537109375 ms. So, it seems there are some malicious vandals on SO?

Comment: I added [a realistic performance test which resemble the OP's production environment](https://jsbench.me/2flby3l6tp/1). And of cause an approach which due to a nested `findIndex` tasks (it's another iteration though it exists early) already implements exponential costs will fall back far behind any lookup based approach. In chrome, firefox, safari the latter is everywhere in between 80% to 84% percent slower than a lookup and reference based approach.

Comment: _"So, it seems there are some malicious vandals on SO?"_ ... I think the downvotes are due to the nested `findIndex` within the context of having to iterate 50 times each in between 1 to 100.000 items (which is gambling regarding performance costs).

Comment: Is there something wrong with my benchmark? https://jsbench.me/0mlbyglzra/1

Comment: The explanation is pretty simple. Your test case creates two arrays where with every iteration of the 50 items array the `findIndex` based search is always successful within the first 50 items of the 100.000 items array which of cause is not a realistic test scenario. Look into how my test case creates a 50 items array which is closer to what one can expect from a production environment. The lookup takes over when it comes to a full covering of a real 50 times 100.000 matrix and not just for the coverage of an effective 50 times 50 matrix as provided with your test case.